# Homework: Magic Plant Recursion Exercise in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion

To make it clear, this IS a graded assignment for my Programming II class. I've generally been very easily receptive to new programming concepts but this particular assignment on recursion is really throwing me and I'm looking for some good nudging in the right direction. Below is the assignment verbatim and the code I currently already have.

**Magic Plant**

We have a magic plant that once it is planted, it germinates and grows two leaves in the first year. It doubles its leaves every year except that every three years it triples its leaves. Something like:

[image: Link to table displayed in my homework document]

Write a class called MagicPlant that includes the following methods:

- A method that returns the number of leaves given the age of the plant
- A non-recursive method that returns the age of the plant given the number of leaves.
- A recursive method that returns the age of the plant given the number of leaves.

In a driver class test the methods.

Find out what is the largest (oldest) plant that your algorithm and data structure can handle.

---

That is what I was given and I'm having trouble on the last bullet point as well as a bit muddy on the second one (but I have code that seems to work).

My current code excluding the Driver class since it's just call statements:

```
public class MagicPlant {

    // Method that returns the number of leaves given
    // the age of the plant.
    public int getLeaves(int age) {
        int leafCount = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= age; i++) {
            if (i % 3 != 0) {
                leafCount *= 2;
            } else {
                leafCount *= 3;
            }
        }
        return leafCount;
    }

    // Non-recursive method that returns the age of the plant
    // given the number of leaves.
    public int getAgeNR(int leaves) {
        int age = 1;
        while (leaves > getLeaves(age)) {
            age++;
        }
        return age;
    }

    // Recursive method that returns the age of the plant
    // given the number of leaves.
    public int getAgeR(int leaves) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Believe or not, we're familiar with this exercise. I've seen the question pop up at least twice before in the last few days.

Comment: @Kayaman Might very well be from my class. Haha. I didn't find any from searching though.

Comment: what should happen when you give in a number which doesn't directly match to an age?

Comment: @Lino Not outlined, but I'm assuming it should take the floored answer. AKA 47 leaves would be 4 years old, not 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tipp is, to replace the `while`-loop with recursion. So you don't have a local variable but instead give that variable back into the method (recursive).

Also i would suggest that you make 2 methods for the recursion:

```
public int getAgeR(int leaves){
     return getAgeR(1, leaves); // call overload with initial value
}

private int getAgeR(int age, int leaves){
     // do your magic here
}
```

Comment: I chose this as the correct answer specifically because it is a nudge and not just the answer outright. Though Skeith's answer _does_ work, I was able to figure it out before it was posted. So thanks!

Comment: @Nic glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Recursive method that returns the age of the plant
// given the number of leaves.
public int getAgeR(int leaves) {
    if(leaves == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(leaves % 3 == 0) {
        return getAgeR(leaves/3)+1;         
    } else {
        return getAgeR(leaves/2)+1;
    } 
}
```

It's the inverse of counting years. Instead of starting from the beginning, you just have to start from the end and decreasing for every recurrent loop.

Comment: Why do the homework for him? Doesn't help him if he just get's solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I asked for a nudge instead of the answer outright, I was able to dissect this and understand it.